# How to update ApexChart?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, apexcharts

I'm using ng-apexcharts on my projects but I'm having an issue. I'm trying to update a chart, I followed the documentation by using the `updateSeries()` method but I get this error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.chart.updateSeries')

The method that does is update is this:

```
changeData(numberOfDays: number) {
    const zoomData = this.chartData;
    zoomData.sort( (a, b) => {
      return b.date - a.date;
    } );
    zoomData.splice(numberOfDays, zoomData.length);
    this.chart.updateSeries([{
      data: zoomData.map(el => el.close)
    }]);
}
```

The data that's on zoomData is:

```
[
   {
      "date":1614297600000,
      "close":121.260002
   },
   {
      "date":1614211200000,
      "close":120.989998
   },
   {
      "date":1614124800000,
      "close":125.349998
   }
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you initialized your object `this.chart`? I think you should initiallized that object in the `constructor` or  `ngOnInit() `.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the issue. When using the `ng-apexcharts`, the update should be like:

```
public updateSeries() {
    this.chartOptions.series = [{
      data: [23, 44, 1, 22]
    }];
  }
```

The `chartOptions` is the initial property set for the chart.